# Python convert zip file to bytes stream

Tags: python, io, zip

I have a zip file that when I open it locally it looks great. I want to convert it to a bytes stream `buffer` and then return it as `HttpResponse(buffer)` using `django`. The code is,

```
studies_zip = zipfile.ZipFile('./studies.zip', 'r')
buffer = io.BytesIO()
bytes = [zipfile.Path(studies_zip, at=file.filename).read_bytes() 
             for file in studies_zip.infolist()]

buffer = io.BytesIO()
buffer_writer = io.BufferedWriter(buffer)
[buffer_writer.write(b) for b in bytes]
buffer.seek(0)

response = HttpResponse(buffer)
response['Content-Type'] = 'application/zip'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=studies.zip'
```

At the front-end/UI I get this,

[image]

that looks fine i.e. the displayed size of `34.9MB` is a little bit less than the actual `36.6MB`. Also, when I try to open the file either on the spot or after saving it locally, I get

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: As an aside, please don't use list-comprehensions for side-effects: `[buffer_writer.write(b) for b in bytes]
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the contents of the compressed files, omitting the metadata contained in the zip archive.

There is no reason to open the file as a zip file as no changes are made to the contents, so just open the file in byes mode and send it. I haven't tested this, but try this:

```
with open('./studies.zip', 'rb') as f:
    response = HttpResponse(f)
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/zip'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=studies.zip'
```